# passing a shells output to a perl script log

Tags: perl, shell, logging

what this script does is pull down a list of usernames and passowrds and hashes it and then adds it to 
a list. When there are non asci characters, the quotemeta escapes them, which allows to htpasswd command to 
consume the vaule. When I run it it prints the results of  /usr/local/apache2/bin/htpasswd to the terminal. 
I want to pass all the results to a file

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings;
use DBI;
use File::Copy;

unshift @INC,"/production/lib";
require "config.pl";
$configFile = "/production/cfg/syncUsers.cfg";
readConfig($configFile);

#doBackup($prefs{passwdFile});
generatePasswdFile("tmpusers");
getUsers($prefs{dbUser},$prefs{dbPass},$prefs{dbSid});
#copyPasswdFile($prefs{passwdFile});

# getUsers - grab user from the db and set them up
sub getUsers { 
    $dbUser = shift;
    $dbPass = shift;
    $dbSid  = shift;
    $dbh =  DBI->connect("dbi:Oracle:$dbSid","$dbUser","$dbPass") or die( "Couldn't connect: $!" );
    $sql = "SELECT user_name,passwd FROM login_tbl";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    while ( ( $user_name,$passwd ) = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
            $user_name = quotemeta($user_name);
            $passwd = quotemeta($passwd);
            #print "$user_name,$passwd\n";
            updatePasswdFile($user_name,$passwd);   
    }
    $dbh->disconnect();
}

# generatePasswdFile - generate a dummy file to start with
sub generatePasswdFile {
    $file = shift;
    $cmd = "$prefs{htpasswd} -bc /tmp/$file dummyuser dummyuser";
    system($cmd); 
}

# updatePasswdFile - update the passwdfile
sub updatePasswdFile {
    $file = "/tmp/tmpusers"; 
    $user = shift;
    $pass = shift;
    print "Adding user: $user\n";
    $cmd = "$prefs{htpasswd} -b $file $user $pass";
    system($cmd);
}
```

this is what it does its I print out to screen.

```
Adding user: dev_ops
Adding password for user dev_ops
Adding user: dev_shed
Adding password for user dev_shed
Adding user: robogrl
Adding password for user robogrl
Adding user: a_foo
Adding password for user a_foo
Adding user: atank
Adding password for user atank
Adding user: acar
Adding password for user acar
Adding user: acarlson
Adding password for user acarlson
Adding user: dnick
Adding password for user dnick
```

When I pass it to a  file so I can check for errors only one half goes to a file 
and the other half is output to the screen.

```
bash-3.00$ ./caspser.pl > /tmp/checkFORerrors2013Nov19
```

this output still goes to the screen -

```
Adding password for user dev_ops
Adding password for user dev_shed
Adding password for user robogrl
Adding password for user a_foo
Adding password for user atank
Adding password for user acar
Adding password for user acarlson
Adding password for user dnick
```

and this goes to the file

```
Adding user: dev_ops
Adding user: dev_shed
Adding user: robogrl
Adding user: a_foo
Adding user: atank
Adding user: acar
Adding user: acarlson
Adding user: dnick
```

how do i get everything to go to a file?
better yet - is there a way to just print errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `htpasswd` command you use prints to `STDERR` (standard error). The redirect you have performed redirects `STDOUT` (standard out) into the file. To redirect both, you need to update your command:

```
bash-3.00$ ./caspser.pl > /tmp/checkFORerrors2013Nov19 2>&1
```

Basically, errors are printed to a different stream. Both streams are showing in the terminal without redirections, and the difference only becomes obvious when you start changing them.

Comment: Or use `>&` to redirect both at once.